# Extract a single file from a zip file only knowing the extension

Tags: files, zip

My first part of the requirement:

I would like to extract a single file from `ex1234.zip`.  The structure and contents of `ex1234.zip`:

```
ex1234 (directory)
    directory1
    ex1234 (directory)
    directory2
    ex1234.csv
```

I want to be able to extract only `ex1234.csv` file but will not know the name.

Second part is to able to do this for all `exXXXX.zip` that sit in the same directory.

```
ex1234.zip
ex3245.zip
ex8829.zip
exXXXX.zip…
```

Output will be:

```
ex1234.csv
ex3245.csv
ex8829.csv
exXXXX.csv
```

Real sample:

```
$ less CW2178470.zip
Archive:  CW2178470.zip
Zip file size: 26108 bytes, number of entries: 26
-rw----     2.0 fat      108 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470.csv
-rw----     2.0 fat     1363 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/config/BusinessContactApprovers.csv
-rw----     2.0 fat      158 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/announcements.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1037 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/Plan/plan.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      141 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/Plan/tasks.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     2408 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/FI_Doc208411460_doc.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      215 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/MessageBoard/nb_27482kst.26ihyzj_.htm
-rw----     2.0 fat     2364 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/MessageBoard/messageboard.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1250 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/team.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat    22016 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/Doc208411460.doc
-rw----     2.0 fat     9973 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/audithistory.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     6731 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/CW2178470/ws.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      308 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/WSFolder.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat     4897 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/Task.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat      770 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/ContractWorkspace.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat     4754 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/AuditHistory.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat    25564 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/CommonTypes.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat     5657 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/MessageBoard.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat     2471 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/Plan.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat      337 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/InternalContractWorkspace.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat     1045 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/SalesContractRequest.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat     3133 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/FolderItem.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat      906 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/ContractRequest.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat     8973 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/WorkspaceTypes.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat     4645 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/Team.xsd
-rw----     2.0 fat      781 bl defN 15-Aug-04 09:37 CW2178470/xsd/SalesContractWorkspace.xsd
26 files, 112005 bytes uncompressed, 21940 bytes compressed:  80.4%
(END)
```

Comment: Can you do a `less ex1234.zip` and paste the exact output ?

Comment: Was a bit lengthy but I added a real sample to the post that wouldn't fit here.

Comment: Does the csv file name always match the zip file name?

Comment: You'd have to write a script(let) that lists the contents of the zipfile, single out the exact file you want, and then extract just that one. Do it by hand, unless this is a routine task. If it is, use your favorite scripting language to cobble something together.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `unzip` like this:

```
unzip -j file[.zip] [file] [-x xfile]
```

where `-j` means junk paths, `file[.zip]` is your archive name, `[file]` is the archive member to be processed and `[-x xfile]` is the list of archive members to be excluded from processing. All these options are described in detail in the man page.
So in your case, running for example:

```
unzip -j ex1234.zip '*/*.csv' -x '*/*/*'
```

will extract in the current directory all files matching `*.csv` from depth level 2 in the `ex1234.zip` archive (excluding archive members from depth level 3 and below as `'*/*/*'` means paths that match at least two `/`).

Now, to process all the archives in the current directory you could run:

```
for zipfile in *.zip; do unzip -j "$zipfile" '*/*.csv' -x '*/*/*'; done
```

which extracts the `.csv` file from each archive in the current directory (that's why `-j` is needed).
In your particular case, there's no `.csv` on level 1 depth so you could also run:

```
for zipfile in *.zip; do unzip -j "$zipfile" '*.csv' -x '*/*/*'; done
```

which should yield the same result.
To dry-run and see which files will be extracted (their archive paths) without actually extracting them, replace `-j` with `-qql`:

```
for zipfile in *.zip; do unzip -qql "$zipfile" '*/*.csv' -x '*/*/*'; done
```

---

As a side note, the `-j` option could be omitted *iff* the `.csv` files to be extracted were on depth level 1 (i.e. no parent dir); in that case you could simply run:

```
for zipfile in *.zip; do unzip "$zipfile" '*.csv' -x '*/*'; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with unzip provided by Debian:

`UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.`

```
for file in ex*.zip
do
  unzip -j $file '*.csv'
done
```

Comment: This is a very good answer but is it possible to only limit to ex1234 directory (very first directory) because I do not want other CSV files that may exist in other folders.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)-based filesystem to access the zip file as a directory tree. Mount each zip file, then access it with normal method (shell wildcards, `cp` command, etc.).

With [fuse-zip](https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip):

```
mkdir mnt
for z in *.zip; do
  fuse-zip -- "$z" mnt
  set mnt/*.csv
  if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Skipping $z because it contains multiple .csv files"
  elif ! [ -e "$1" ]; then
    echo "Skipping $z because it does not contain a .csv file"
  else
    cp -- "$1" "${z%.zip}.csv"
  fi
  fusermount -u mnt
done
```

You can do the same with [`archivemount`](http://www.cybernoia.de/software/archivemount/) instead of `fuse-zip`.

There's also [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) which works differently: it creates a view of the whole filesystem under `~/.avfs`; in this view, if you have an archive file `/path/to/foo.zip`, you can access it as a directory under the name `~/.avfs/path/to/foo.zip#`.

```
mountavfs
cd "$HOME/.avfs$PWD"
for z in *.zip; do
  set -- "$z#/"*.csv
  if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Skipping $z because it contains multiple .csv files"
  elif ! [ -e "$1" ]; then
    echo "Skipping $z because it does not contain a .csv file"
  else
    cp "$1" "${z%.zip}.csv"
  fi
done
```

If you use a shell with arrays and with a way to get an empty list when a wildcard doesn't match, you can get a slightly more readable script. For example, in ksh93, with fuse-zip:

```
#!/bin/ksh
mkdir mnt
for z in *.zip; do
  fuse-zip -- "$z" mnt
  csv=(~(N)"$z/"*.csv)
  if ((${#csv[@]} > 1)); then
    echo "Skipping $z because it contains multiple .csv files"
  elif ((${#csv[@]} == 0)); then
    echo "Skipping $z because it does not contain a .csv file"
  else
    cp -- "$1" "${z%.zip}.csv"
  fi
  fusermount -u mnt
done
```

In zsh, use `csv=($z/*.csv(N))`. In bash, use `csv=($z/*.csv)` but first run `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: Very thorough answer unfortunately our environment doesn't have either tools (fuse, AVFS) nor do I have authority over it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You suggest that all the names have to match:

- The ZIP filename
- The directory name inside the ZIP file
- The CSV file inside the directory

In that case, try:

```
for zipfile in ./*.zip; do
    base="$(basename "$zipfile" .zip)"
    unzip "$zipfile" "$base/$base.csv"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that all the files match this pattern - from `CW2178470.zip` you need to always extract `CW2178470/CW2178470.csv`

This is relatively easy:

```
for i in ./*.zip
do
   SERIAL=$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's,^.*/,,' -e 's,.zip$,,' )
   unzip "$i" "${SERIAL}/${SERIAL}.csv"
done
```

If you need smarter logic than that, I'd probably start looking at `perl` and `Archive::Zip` to extract.

Comment: Thanks! This works too, but folder is constructed with csv file inside.  i.e ex1234/ex1234.csv ...

Comment: `unzip -j` is your friend there.